# How to group a set of rows until a different value is found and maintaining order

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
ref_id  |  sku  | ordered
===========================
16      | 39562 |   0
16      | 39562 |   0
16      | 39562 |   0
16      | 91355 |   0
16      | 39562 |   0
16      | 39562 |   0
17      | 39562 |   0
17      | 39562 |   1
17      | 39562 |   1
```

And I'd like to iterate through the rows, where it groups elements that have the same value across the row until a different value is found. Therefore, the output for the table above would look like this:

```
ref_id  |  sku  | ordered
===========================
16      | 39562 |   0
16      | 91355 |   0
16      | 39562 |   0
17      | 39562 |   0
17      | 39562 |   1
```

The challenge I have is the "ordered" column where I'm using MAX(ordered) to group by.

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS ref_id, sku, MAX(ordered)
FROM db
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY ref_id, timeInfo
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  What column specifies the ordering?

Comment: @GordonLinoff there's a timeInfo column (not displayed, but users to order) that sets the ordering (typical ISO time format). `db` is a CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()`.  Assuming `timeinfo` specifies the ordering of the columns:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(timeinfo) over (partition by refid order by timeinfo) as prev_timeinfo,
             lag(timeinfo) over (partition by refid, sku, ordered order by timeinfo) as prev_timeinfo_rso
      from db t
     ) t
where prev_timeinfo_rso is null or
      prev_timeinfo_rso <> prev_timeinfo;
```

Comment: This definitely solved it. `LAG()` is definitely something new for me. Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: I found a minor spelling error I cannot edit in the following line `where pre_timeinfo_rso is null or` for you - can you add a `v` to `pre`.

Comment: @Adib Just adding a tiny bit extra information in case you're not familiar. `LAG()` isn't the only function that behaves over a group of rows, even if it is the proper choice here. There is a small collection of [analytic functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/analytic-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that are supported by most implementations of SQL (sometimes just with different names).