# How to count number of records same value adjacent value mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+-----+-------+
| id  | status|
+-----+-------+
| 01  | open  |
| 02  | close |
| 03  | close |
| 04  | close |
| 05  | open  |
| 06  | open  |
| 07  | open  |
| 08  | close |
| 09  | open  |
| 10  | close |
+-----+-------+
```

My expect:

- get a number of records same value adjacent value
- example:

| status | number |
| --- | --- |
| open | 1 |
| close | 3 |
| open | 3 |
| close | 1 |
| open | 1 |
| close | 1 |

Comment: You can use LEAD or LAG for that, see here: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lead-function/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group a set of rows until a different value is found and maintaining order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68505790/how-to-group-a-set-of-rows-until-a-different-value-is-found-and-maintaining-orde)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, you may use the difference between two `row_number` functions to define unique groups for consecutive similar 'status' values, then perform aggregation based on that groups. Check the following:

```
select status, count(*) number
from
(
  select *,
    row_number() over (order by cast(id as signed)) - 
    row_number() over (partition by status order by cast(id as signed)) grp
  from table_name
) T
group by status, grp
order by grp
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/lveI0zNk).

For MySQL 5.7, try the following:

```
set @g=0;
set @sts=null;
select status, count(*) number
from
(
  select *,
    if(@sts<>status, @g:=@g+1, @g) grp, @sts:=status
  from table_name
  order by cast(id as signed)
) T
group by status, grp
order by grp
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y9hWFKly).